# Android Webview doesn't always synchronize document.cookie

Tags: android, cookies, webview

Using Android 6.0 (at least) with Android System WebView on my application.

When JavaScript sets "document.cookie" on a full page load, it seems to synchronize the new cookie with CookieManager straight away.

However, if I load an ajax page which sets another document.cookie, it won't sync anytime soon. I've been spending HOURS trying to understand why was this "sometimes" working, sometimes not, until I realized the problem was with the ajax one, only.

I've resolved this issue by just creating a `@JavascriptInterface` method that JavaScript invokes every time it sets a cookie, and all this method does is:

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

It works!
But Android Studio is warning me that **CookieSyncManager is deprecated**.

I read in other questions that we don't need to do this manual sync anymore, because Android manages the sync itself, but in this case I really want all cookies to be always synchronized.

If CookieSyncManager gets removed in a future Android API, what is then the best way to make sure the cookies are always synchronized as soon as they are set?